# google analytics not working for mobile website

Tags: google-analytics

I have a problem with Google Analytics iframe tracking. I have iframes for each of my mobile webpages but it only tracks the main page, however when user clicks on any links it directs to the different url but the url at the top remains same as it is loading without refreshing and I am calling them.

Here is the link of my url which is targeted for mobile but even from pc other links are not coming in Google Analytics

This is the link whose analytics is in gatouch.html

```
       http://way2enjoy.com/touch/default.php
```

But when user clicks on any link

```
   picquote

    music

    wallpaper

    download
```

It takes the user to a different url but the top url in browser remains same and content of those urls are loaded, but Google Analytics of all urls are different but its not coming in google analytics tracking data.

Does anyone know where I am doing mistake will be a great help

I want to track data from all urls.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be possible by using _getLinkerUrl() in your GA tracking code. Please refer to the [GA documentation for more details](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#trackingIFrames), I am sure this will help.